# Nginx+Gunicorn+Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Подскажите, пожалуйста, или научите гуглить:) 
Как я понял, nginx работает с http запросами от клиента и через gunicorn обращается к Django. Nginx и gunicorn используют смешанный подход к обработке запросто , а именно асинхронный , пул потоков и тд. Но Django синхронный.( если что-то не верно - исправьте меня ) Как это работает в связке? Как обрабатываются например 10,100,1000 и тд одновременных запросов? И если внутри views я создам функцию с while true , которая будет работать , пока например в бд не появится какая-то запись , чтобы вернуть через ajax информацию о готовности клиенту в браузер - заблочит ли этот while true процессы всех остальных клиентов?

Comment: Заблочит всех остальных клиентов, которые попали в тот же самый процесс/поток. Если вы например запустите 4 процесса (опция workers в gunicorn, ну или threads если угодно), то остальные клиенты будут обслуживаться в трёх оставшихся процессах и всё будет хорошо. А если while true запустится во всех четырёх процессах, то свободных процессов не останется и печальбеда

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Можете чуть подробнее рассказать как это работает. Ну или ссылочку какую дать ? Я в том плане , если я выставлю 4 worker - создадутся 4 отдельных независимых процесса django?

Comment: Создадутся 4 отдельных независимых процесса gunicorn, и каждый из них запустит свою копию django внутри себя

Comment: Понял , большое спасибо! Последний вопрос , внутри одного воркера gunicorn как Джанго обслуживает n-количество клиентов? n>1